# Is there a way to read data from redis server using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, redis, data-analysis

I'm working on a project with IoT devices that are connected to a dotnet server hosted in the Azure cloud. I'm currently using for loops to read real-time data but want to read some real-time stats from the Redis database using Pandas. Can Someone explain to me the way how to start with?

Using the below script to read stats but want to start using pandas.

```
import os
import re
import json
import traceback
from collections import Counter
import time
import datetime as dt
import redis
from tqdm import tqdm  # taqadum (تقدّم) == progress
from jsonpointer import resolve_pointer as j_get 
from jsonpointer import JsonPointerException
import pandas as pd

os.system("color 0c")  # change console color to red

if False:
    # x Redis
    r = redis.Redis(host="****.redis.cache.windows.net", 
                    port=***,
                    password="***",
                    ssl=True,)
else:
    # y Redis
    r = redis.Redis(host="***.redis.cache.windows.net", 
                    port=****,
                    password="*****",
                    ssl=True,)


print(r.info())
print("Server started at: ", end="")
print(dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(seconds=r.info()['uptime_in_seconds']))

print("Building pipe")
pipe = r.pipeline()
# for key in tqdm(r.scan_iter("MC:SessionInfo*")):
for key in tqdm(r.scan_iter("MC:SessionInfo*", count=2500)):
    pipe.hgetall(key)

print("Executing pipe")
responses = pipe.execute()
print("Processing effluvia")


q = {}
k={}
first = True
last_contact = {}
for data in tqdm(responses):
    try:
        j = json.loads(data[b'LastStatusBody'])
        serial = j['System']['Serial'].lower()
     
        q[serial] = j
        last_contact[serial] = time.time() - int(data[b'LastContact'])
        # TODO: json searching sensibly!
        vac[serial] = j['LiveA']['Unit']['Volatge_Vac']
    except:
        if first:
            traceback.print_exc()
            first = False
        else:
            pass

for key,value in fw_versions.items():
    if value.split(',')[0]=="xx v1.0.0.0":
        x_paired.append(key)
print(x_paired)
print("Total paired :", len(x_paired))`
```

Instead of the above procedure want to start with Pandas to read data easily and do some charts for daily updates to the team.

Answer (score 0):

I serialize / deserialize to `pyarrow` or `pickle` and then use an additional key as meta data.  This works across local, GCloud, AWS EB and Azure

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa, os
import redis,json, os, pickle
import ebutils
from logenv import logenv
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
from redis.client import Redis
from typing import (Union, Optional)


class mycache():
    __redisClient:Redis
    CONFIGKEY = "cacheconfig"

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        try:
            ep = os.environ["REDIS_HOST"]
        except KeyError:
            if os.environ["HOST_ENV"] == "GCLOUD":
                os.environ["REDIS_HOST"] = "redis://10.0.0.3"
            elif os.environ["HOST_ENV"] == "EB":
                os.environ["REDIS_HOST"] = "redis://" + ebutils.get_redis_endpoint()
            elif os.environ["HOST_ENV"] == "AZURE":
                #os.environ["REDIS_HOST"] = "redis://ignore:password@redis-sensorvenv.redis.cache.windows.net"
                pass # should be set in azure env variable
            elif os.environ["HOST_ENV"] == "LOCAL":
                os.environ["REDIS_HOST"] = "redis://127.0.0.1"
            else:
                raise "could not initialise redis"
                return # no known redis setup

        #self.__redisClient = redis.Redis(host=os.environ["REDIS_HOST"])
        self.__redisClient = redis.Redis.from_url(os.environ["REDIS_HOST"])
        self.__redisClient.ping()
        # get config as well...
        self.config = self.get(self.CONFIGKEY)
        if self.config is None:
            self.config = {"pyarrow":True, "pickle":False}
            self.set(self.CONFIGKEY, self.config)
        self.alog = logenv.alog()

    def redis(self) -> Redis:
        return self.__redisClient


    def exists(self, key:str) -> bool:
        if self.__redisClient is None:
            return False

        return self.__redisClient.exists(key) == 1

    def get(self, key:str) -> Union[DataFrame, str]:
        keytype = "{k}.type".format(k=key)
        valuetype = self.__redisClient.get(keytype)
        if valuetype is None:
            if (key.split(".")[-1] == "pickle"):
                return pickle.loads(self.redis().get(key))
            else:
                ret = self.redis().get(key)
                if ret is None:
                    return ret
                else:
                    return ret.decode()
        elif valuetype.decode() == str(pd.DataFrame):
            # fallback to pickle serialized form if pyarrow fails
            # https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-7961
            try:
                return pa.deserialize(self.__redisClient.get(key))
            except pa.lib.ArrowIOError as err:
                self.alog.warning("using pickle from cache %s - %s - %s", key, pa.__version__, str(err))
                return pickle.loads(self.redis().get(f"{key}.pickle"))
            except OSError as err:
                if "Expected IPC" in str(err):
                    self.alog.warning("using pickle from cache %s - %s - %s", key, pa.__version__, str(err))
                    return pickle.loads(self.redis().get(f"{key}.pickle"))
                else:
                    raise err

        elif valuetype.decode() == str(type({})):
            return json.loads(self.__redisClient.get(key).decode())
        else:
            return self.__redisClient.get(key).decode() # type: ignore

    def set(self, key:str, value:Union[DataFrame, str]) -> None:
        if self.__redisClient is None:
            return
        keytype = "{k}.type".format(k=key)

        if str(type(value)) == str(pd.DataFrame):
            self.__redisClient.set(key, pa.serialize(value).to_buffer().to_pybytes())
            if self.config["pickle"]:
                self.redis().set(f"{key}.pickle", pickle.dumps(value))
                # issue should be transient through an upgrade....
                # once switched off data can go away
                self.redis().expire(f"{key}.pickle", 60*60*24)
        elif str(type(value)) == str(type({})):
            self.__redisClient.set(key, json.dumps(value))
        else:
            self.__redisClient.set(key, value)

        self.__redisClient.set(keytype, str(type(value)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ["HOST_ENV"] = "LOCAL"
    r = mycache()
    rr = r.redis()
    for k in rr.keys("cache*"):
        print(k.decode(), rr.ttl(k))
        print(rr.get(k.decode()))
```

Comment: i cannot find the libraries ebutils and  logenv. Could you add the link to them?

Comment: **ebutils** are the AWS client libraries, you can remove the dependency if using Azure.  **logenv** is my own wrapper around python logging, again can be removed.  It's not a standalone reproducible piece of code,  just a clear demonstration it's simple to use **redis** with any of the major cloud platforms to store serialised pandas data frames